# Getting an Error: slugify: string argument expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, slug, slugify

I try to create category to eCommerce project then it throws an error
[Postman - throws an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYiBm.png)

These are source codes

location: ecommerce-backend\index.js

```
    const express = require('express')
    const env = require('dotenv')
    const app = express()
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')


    //routes
    const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth')
    const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin/auth')
    const categoryRoutes = require('./routes/category')
    const productRoutes = require('./routes/product')
    const cartRoutes = require('./routes/cart')
    //environment variable or you can say constants
    env.config()

    //mongodb connection
    mongoose.connect(
        `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USERS}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.nglbc.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, 
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true, 
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true
        }
    ).then(() => {
        console.log('Database connected')
    });

    app.use(express.json())
    app.use('/api', authRoutes)
    app.use('/api', adminRoutes)
    app.use('/api', categoryRoutes)
    app.use('/api', cartRoutes)
    app.use('/api', productRoutes)

    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
    })
```

location: ecommerce-backend\routes\category.js

```
    const express = require('express')
    const { requireSignin, adminMiddleware } = require('../common-middleware')
    const { addCategory,getCategories } = require('../controller/category')
    const router = express.Router()
    const path = require('path')
    const shortid = require('shortid')
    const multer = require('multer')

    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'uploads'))
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, shortid.generate() + '-' + file.originalname)
        }
      })

    const upload = multer({ storage })

    router.post('/category/create',requireSignin, adminMiddleware,upload.single('categoryImage'), addCategory)
    router.get('/category/getcategory', getCategories)

    module.exports = router
```

location: ecommerce-backend\models\category.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        slug: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        categoryImage: {
            type: String,
        },
        parentId: {
            type: String
        }

    }, { timestamps: true})

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Category',categorySchema)
```

location: ecommerce-backend\controller\category.js

```
const Category = require('../models/category')
const slugify = require('slugify')

function createCategories(categories, parentId = null){

    const categoryList = []
    let category
    if(parentId == null){
        category = categories.filter(cat => cat.parentId == undefined)
    }else{
        category = categories.filter(cat => cat.parentId == parentId)
    }

    for(let cate of category){
        categoryList.push({
            _id: cate._id,
            name: cate.name,
            slug: cate.slug,
            children: createCategories(categories,cate._id)
        })
    }

    return categoryList
}

exports.addCategory = (req, res) => {

    const categoryObj = {
        name: req.body.name,
        slug: slugify(req.body.name)
    }

    if(req.file){
            categoryObj.categoryImage = process.env.API + '/public/'+ req.file.filename
    }

    if(req.body.parentId){
        categoryObj.parentId = req.body.parentId
    }

    const cat = new Category(categoryObj)
    cat.save((error,category) => {
        if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error})
        if(category){
            return res.status(201).json({ category})
        }
    })
}

exports.getCategories = (req,res) => {
    Category.find({})
    .exec((error, categories) => {
        if(error) return res.status(400).json({error})

        if(categories){

            const categoryList = createCategories(categories)

            res.status(200).json({categoryList})
        }
    })
}
```

this is my .env file at ecommerce-backend\ .env

```
PORT = 2000
MONGO_DB_USERS = mrzombit
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD = ********
MONGO_DB_DATABASE = ecommerce
JWT_SECRET = MERNSECRET
API = http://localhost:2000
```

I face this problem then I can't figure it out what happened to my code
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have change the 'Content-Type' in postman header section.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with the following code which I hope would work for you.

```
**slug: slugify(toString(req.body.name))**
```

Comment: this approach worked for me event after updating the slugify npm

Answer (score 0):

I just do below steps:

1. Delete **slugify** package from `package.json`
2. Reinstall **slugify** package : you will see that

   found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
3. Run `npm audit fix`
4. Open new window ! in postman and
   copy the token from `/api/admin/create` and paste this token in the new window: `/api/category/create` in body ,

   form-data :

   name (doesn't exist in your DB yet)

   categoryImage (click file not text)

Answer (score 0):

Add
`slug: { type: String, slug: "title"}` to your model.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug the problem of `slugify: string argument expected` & found that in my case `this` object is comeing as `{}` so it was throwing `slugify: string argument expected`.
try to find if all values are properly received in slugify method.

Code snippet

```
Schema.pre('save', (next)=> {
  console.log(`pre hook is triggered ${this.name}`.silly);
  // this.set({ updatedAt: new Date() });
  this.slug = slugify(this.name,{lower:true})
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes again maybe one not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Even I was also getting same error while I was doing this ecommerce clone project by a watching a tutorial. I tried few things which didn't work. But you can try those by doing following things:

1. Try setting slug to:

```
slug: slugify(toString(name))
```

2. Try getting saved data in console:

```
console.log(category)
```

If you are **not getting name in  the console** and you are getting all other objects. Don't worry, just **try fourth step**.

3. Check whether your `Content-type` is set to:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>
```

4. Lastly, my error got solved by doing changes in postman **by re-arranging the position of name in the form-data** and sending name in the last **part/place of the request**. You may feel this thing silly but it worked for me. If this step solves your error and the data gets saved. Delete the data from collection and try sending name in the first place and hopefully it will work normally.